# How many features do you generally use for your ML Model?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am working on a certain kaggle competition and users there say that they are using >5000 features and training a XGBoost or Random Forest on it.

The mentioned post is here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-trip-type-classification/forums/t/17258/feature-counts

I tried doing so myself after exploding the feature space and creating interaction features, but it takes forever to run on my 16GB macbook. 
For example: (96000,1000) data took around 5 hrs to finish to train an RF with n_estimators=1000,max_depth=40, cv=3.

Tuning such a model would take weeks and it only uses 1000 predictors....

Now here are some of my doubts:
1. Is my python scikit environment properly loaded. I use anaconda distribution. Are these running times normal?

Answer (score 0):

The number of features should take into account the [number of examples](http://fastml.com/how-much-data-is-enough/) you have in the training data.

If your model training takes too long, have you considered principal components analysis or [feature selection](http://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/)?  Both techniques can cut down the number of features into a more manageable size without throwing away information which describes the target variable.